# Installshield 2009 and Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable Package

Tags: visual-studio-2015, installshield, installshield-2009

Having just upgraded my application to .net 4.5 and VS 2015, I also need to update my installer (in Installshield 2009).

I managed to get my hands on the prq file for the Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable Package from the latest Installshield (got the demo). And it seems to work OK in 2009. But:

- It refuses to auto download the file (from within Installshield).
- After manually downloading the file, and putting it in the right location, and it showing as "Downloaded" in Installshield, it wont include it in the installer
- When I go to install my application, it downloads the C++ redistributable (I'm fine with this I guess), and then installs it, but never seems to finish. Cancelling it doesnt help - it just starts cancelling forever. After a reboot, the C++ redistributable is installed.

So, the problem seems to be that the redistributable is installed, but the overall installer isnt aware of it, so it keeps waiting. Can I do anything about this? I'd prefer to keep using the 2009 version if I can (installshield is not cheap).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can try to remake your own PRQ with the *Installshield prerequisit editor* that came with your version of installshield. it's actually pretty easy and you can still open the 2015 one for "inspiration".

It should help you understand how it work and will force a recalculation of the filesize and file checksum.

don't forget it's also an XML file that you can edit and read.